# Is mass equivalent to potential energy?

Tags: energy, mass, potential-energy

In other words, do we really need the concept of mass? If so, why?

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* Paul!  I've read the title and the first sentence several times and I just don't see how one is the other in different words.  Would you please add the additional context that ties the title and and first sentence together?

Comment: I second the need of context, but, @AlfredCentauri, I think the OP means that, if mass is equivalent to potential energy, then we don't need to talk about mass -- potential energy alone would do.

Comment: Potential energy in what frame? Relative to what ?

Answer (score 1):

They are separate concepts. This becomes clear in relativity where mass is the norm of the four-momentum and total energy is the time component of the four momentum.

If you are not familiar with the four momentum then consider a photon, it is massless but it has energy. Therefore it is clear that mass and total energy are different things (although they are closely related).

Potential energy is even further removed from the concept of mass, and can have its own challenges to define correctly.

Comment: It would also be worth noting that the split total energy = KE + PE is not always possible, as there could be interactions between bodies which are not potential, thus the conservation of the total energy would not necessarily hold.

Comment: Aren't you talking about the kinetic energy while he question is about the potential energy?

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the answer to be more specific regarding total energy vs potential energy